# WebLogic clustered singleton service

Tags: singleton, weblogic, cluster-computing

I am currently trying to implement a singleton service over **WebLogic**, using a WebLogic cluster.
I've read some literature about clustered singleton services on WebLogic, and I know I have to implement [weblogic.cluster.singleton.SingletonService](http://otndnld.oracle.co.jp/document/products/wls/docs100/javadocs/weblogic/cluster/singleton/SingletonService.html) interface on the object I want to clusterize as a singleton.

```
import weblogic.cluster.singleton.SingletonService;

public class SingletonOrchestrator implements SingletonService {

    public void activate() {
        System.out.println(":: activate CALLED FOR SingletonOrchestrator");
    }
    public void deactivate() {
        System.out.println(":: deactivate CALLED FOR SingletonOrchestrator");
    }

    (...)

}
```

I'm able to deploy this as an application on WebLogic, although it doesn't seem to invoke `activate()` and `deactivate()` methods after deployment. I don't know what else I have to do in order to have this working as a singleton service in my WebLogic cluster.

Does anybody have experience with this? Can anyone provide a working example and explain to me what else I have to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The installation steps are detailed in [Automatic Migration of User-Defined Singleton Services](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/cluster/service_migration.html#wp1051458):

- Implement the  Singleton Service Interface
- Deploy it and Configuring the Migration Behavior

  - Package and deploy the singleton service within an application (in weblogic-application.xml).
    ~ or ~
  - Deploy the singleton service as a standalone service within WebLogic Server (in config.xml).
  - Optionally, configure the migration behavior of the singleton service.

Also have a look at [Configure a Singleton Service](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/ConsoleHelp/taskhelp/clusters/ConfigureSingletonService.html) in the Administration Console Online Help.

Comment: If I had a synchronized method in a POJO deployed as this SingletonService. Would the synchronization be achieved across cluster. I think it will .  We have a need of achieving distributed locks in our weblogic application but don't have the freedom to introduce a new product like hazelcast. Just came across this SingletonService feature. May be this will do the trick. can someone confirm ?

Comment: SingletonService runs on exactly one node, so nothing to get synchronized across nodes.