# A question on clustered environment on Weblogic server

Tags: java, weblogic

I am using Weblogic 10g clustered environment to deploy my application.  In my application, I have used a class `Cache.java` to load some properties from database lazily.  This is how it works.  `Cache.java` is a singleton class with instance variables as cache objects.  For example, one of the instance variables is `List<String> STORES_IN_CITY`.  This cache is null when the clusters start.  The actual values are in database.  The implementation of the class is given below:

```
public class Cache
{
    private List<String> STORES_IN_CITY;

    private static final Cache cache=new Cache();

    public static Cache getCache()
    {
        return cache;
    {

    private Cache()
    {
        // private constructor to have singleton class
    }

    public List<String> getStoresInCity()
    {
        if(null==STORES_IN_CITY || STORES_IN_CITY.size()==0){
             STORES_IN_CITY=getStoresFromDatabase();
        }
        return STORES_IN_CITY;
    }
}
```

My question here is that there are multiple calls to database for getting the cache STORES_IN_CITY.  I believe this is because of the clustered environment, as for each server, there is a different JVM instance and a copy of cache.  So depending on which server is hit for a request at runtime, the database call is made.  I want to have a single cache across servers.  Is this possible?

I hope the I have elaborated on my question enough.  If any further explanation is needed, please let me know.

Thanks,
Siddharth

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> (...) I believe this is because of the clustered environment, as for each server, there is a different JVM instance and a copy of cache.

This is correct.

> I want to have a single cache across servers. Is this possible?

You could implement a `weblogic.cluster.singleton.SingletonService` (*A singleton service is a service running on a managed server that is available on only one member of a cluster at a time*).

#### Resources

- [Define a New Singleton Service](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/ConsoleHelp/taskhelp/clusters/DefineSingletonService.html)
- [Configure a Singleton Service](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/ConsoleHelp/taskhelp/clusters/ConfigureSingletonService.html)

#### Related question

- [WebLogic clustered singleton service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461355/weblogic-clustered-singleton-service)

Comment: Thanks a ton!  This will help.  Also, is there a generic API which works with all J2EE compliant servers?

Comment: @SidCool Not really (although Java EE 6 introduces @Singleton EJB but the behavior in a cluster is not specified).

Comment: What about JBoss cache and Hibernate cache?  I am not very sure what they are for.